# Can a HGST Replacement Hard Disk contain the wdidle3 parameter?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, hdparm

```
/dev/sda:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 00 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 00 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 wdidle3      = 42 ??


/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       HGST HTS545050A7E680  
        Firmware Revision:  GR2OA3N0
        Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6; Revision: ATA8-AST T13 Project D1697 Revision 0b
```

**wdidle** is a parameter found on WD hard disks as per man `hdparm` `-J` option

> -J     Get/set  the Western Digital (WD) Green Drive's "idle3" timeout value.  WD  supply  a WDIDLE3.EXE DOS utility for tweaking this setting, and you should use that pro‐gram instead of hdparm if at all possible.

The disk has a HGST label and SMART also lists it as HGST

Do normal HGST laptop 5400RPM disks have this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

All modern hard drives have an equivalent of the parameter.

You can use the windows registry to fix that for any drive:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\iaStor\Parameters]
"Port0AAM"=dword:000000fe
"Port0APM"=dword:000000ff
```

Where port0 is the 1st port where your drive is (replace with needed values).

There are also 3rd party tools that can manage this.

For Linux, you can use **hdparm** for the same result.

Comment: The question is "do normal HGST laptop 5400RPM disks have this parameter?" Where in your "answer" is the answer?

Comment: They all have an equivalent of it.

Comment: It would help to say that explicitly in your answer.

Comment: I updated to include that.

Answer (score 0):

I asked Mr.Mark Lord and he confirmed what was said earlier. All hard disks have a value stored that deals with how frequently hard disks heads are parked prior to entering low power consumption. The '*wdidle3*' string's just something that hdparam uses - it's not stored on disk as a key-name.